# Prove that $\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+....+\frac{1}{2n}\geq \frac{2}{3}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, fractions, arithmetic-progressions, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Prove that for $n \in \mathbb{N}$

(a) $\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+....+\frac{1}{2n}\geq \frac{2}{3}$

And

(b) $\frac{1}{2} \leq \frac{1}{3n+1}+\frac{1}{3n+2}+.....\frac{1}{5n}+\frac{1}{5n+1}+....< \frac{2}{3}$

***my attempt :***

$\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+....+\frac{1}{2n}\\
>\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{2n}+....+\frac{1}{2n}\\
=\frac{n+1}{2n}>\frac{1}{2}$

Where i am missing and how to processed second question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By C-S
$$\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}+...+\frac{1}{2n}\geq\frac{(1+1+...+1)^2}{n+(n+1)+...+(2n)}=\frac{(n+1)^2}{\frac{(n+1)(2n+n)}{2}}=\frac{2(n+1)}{3n}>\frac{2}{3}$$

$$\frac{1}{3n+1}+\frac{1}{3n+2}+.....\frac{1}{5n}+\frac{1}{5n+1}\geq\frac{(1+1+...+1)^2}{(3n+1)+(3n+2)+...+(5n+1)}=$$
$$=\frac{(2n+1)^2}{\frac{(2n+1)(2(3n+1)+2n)}{2}}=\frac{2n+1}{4n+1}>\frac{1}{2}.$$
$$\frac{1}{3n+1}+\frac{1}{3n+2}+.....\frac{1}{5n}+\frac{1}{5n+1}<\int\limits_{3n}^{5n+1}\frac{1}{x}dx=\ln\frac{5n+1}{3n}<\frac{2}{3}$$ for all $n\geq2$.

For $n=1$ we see that $\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}<\frac{2}{3}$ is true.

Comment: ..thank you sir can you give me hint for part (b)

Comment: The first part is wrong because this sum $\rightarrow+\infty.$

Comment: ...you the inequality is not correct right

Comment: Maybe do you mean  $\frac{1}{2} \leq \frac{1}{3n+1}+\frac{1}{3n+2}+.....\frac{1}{5n}+\frac{1}{5n+1}< \frac{2}{3}$?

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg..yes sir

Comment: What does C-S stand for ?

Comment: @marwalix..cauchy schwarz inquality

Comment: Doesn’t look straightforward to me. The general form of C-S is $(a,b)^2\leq (a,a)(b,b)$ where $(a,a)$ is some inner product. In this case $a=(1/\sqrt{n},\cdots,1/\sqrt{2n})$ and $b=(\sqrt{n},\cdots,\sqrt{2n})$ and the inner product is the usual dot product.

Comment: I used the C-S in the following form. Let $b_i>0$. Then: $\frac{a_1^2}{b_1}+\frac{a_2^2}{b_2}+...+\frac{b_n^2}{b_n}\geq\frac{(a_1+a_2+...+a_n)^2}{b_1+b_2+...+b_n}.$