# Solve this: $\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{2n}>\frac{2}{3}$; without induction

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

How can I solve this $\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{2n}>\frac{2}{3}$; using this relation: $AM>HM$?

Comment: Have you tried comparing the AM and HM of the sequence $\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n+1}, \ldots, \frac{1}{2n}$?

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2641211/42969

Comment: How is this related to [harmonic-analysis]?

Answer (score 5):

$$\frac{\sum_{i=n}^{2n}\frac1i}{n+1}\geqslant \frac{n+1}{\sum_{i=n}^{2n}i}=\frac{n+1}{\frac{3}2\cdot n(n+1)}=\frac{2}{3n}\implies \sum_{i=n}^{2n}\frac1i\geqslant \frac23\cdot \frac{n+1}n>\frac23$$

Answer (score 2):

Dr. Mathva has given an AM>HM answer. Here is another approach based on "reflecting" the sum and grouping pairs of terms together.

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n{1\over n+k}&={1\over2}\sum_{k=0}^n\left({1\over n+k}+{1\over2n-k}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\left({1\over3n-(n-2k)}+{1\over3n+(n-2k)} \right)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n{6n\over9n^2-(n-2k)^2}\\
&\ge\sum_{k=0}^n{6n\over9n^2}\\
&={2(n+1)\over3n}\\
&\gt{2\over3}
\end{align}$$

Comment: I did the same thing. You can also get an upper bound.

Answer (score 1):

Since
$\dfrac1{n}
\gt \int_n^{n+1} \dfrac{dt}{t}
$,

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=n}^{2n} \dfrac1{k}
&\gt \sum_{k=n}^{2n} \int_k^{k+1} \dfrac{dt}{t}\\
&= \int_n^{2n+1} \dfrac{dt}{t}\\
&= \ln(2n+1)-\ln(n)\\
&=\ln(2+\frac1{n})\\
&\gt \ln(2)\\
&= 0.693...\\
&\gt \dfrac23\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Right. Thanks, Upvoted and corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an elementary proof
that the sum is between
$\dfrac23$
and
$\dfrac{3(1+\frac1{n})}{4}
$.

$\begin{array}\\
s(n)
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \dfrac1{n+k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \dfrac1{2n-k}\\
\text{so}\\
2s(n)
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n} (\dfrac1{n+k}+\dfrac1{2n-k})\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \dfrac{n+k+2n-k}{(n+k)(2n-k)}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \dfrac{3n}{(n+k)(2n-k)}\\
&=3n\sum_{k=0}^{n} \dfrac1{2n^2+nk-k^2}\\
&=3n\sum_{k=0}^{n} \dfrac1{2n^2+k(n-k)}\\
&\lt 3n\sum_{k=0}^{n} \dfrac1{2n^2}\\
&= 3n\dfrac{n+1}{2n^2}\\
&= \dfrac{3(n+1)}{2n}\\
\text{so}\\
s(n)
&\lt \dfrac{3(1+\frac1{n})}{4}\\
\text{and}\\
2s(n)
&=3n\sum_{k=0}^{n} \dfrac1{2n^2+kn-k^2}\\
&=3n\sum_{k=0}^{n} \dfrac1{2n^2+n^2/4-n^2/4+kn-k^2}\\
&=3n\sum_{k=0}^{n} \dfrac1{2n^2+n^2/4-(k-n/2)^2}\\
&\gt 3n\sum_{k=0}^{n} \dfrac1{2n^2+n^2/4}\\
&\gt 3n\sum_{k=0}^{n} \dfrac{4}{9n^2}\\
&= \dfrac{4(n+1)}{3}\\
&\gt \dfrac43\\
\text{so}\\
s(n)
&\gt \dfrac23\\
\end{array}
$